# How to make Cascading dropdown in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was tried earlier but can't get success in that.

Can anyone tell me with example?

Comment: a lot of tutorials and videos for how to do this step by step so you can follow like this      https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/

Comment: you can use jQuery Ajax call on change of parent dropdown value.  here is an example with category and sub category dropdown list - https://geeksarray.com/blog/cascading-dropdownlist-example-using-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I tried this method too but can't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could refer to the following steps to create a Cascading dropdown in asp.net core MVC.

1. Create models with [relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships):

   ```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "SubCategory Name")]
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Then using [EF core migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to create the related tables in the database, or create a service to set the initial data. Here I create a service:

   ```
    public interface IRepository
    {  
        List<Category> GetCategories(); 
    }

    public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        //you can also query the database and get the data.

        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
            {
                new Category(){ Id=101, CategoryName="Category 1", 
                    SubCategories= new List<SubCategory>(){
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1001, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 1.1"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1002, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 1.2"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1003, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 1.3"},
                    }
                },
                new Category(){ Id=102, CategoryName="Category 2",
                    SubCategories= new List<SubCategory>(){
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1001, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 2.1"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1002, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 2.2"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1003, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 2.3"},
                    }
                },
                new Category(){ Id=103, CategoryName="Category 3",
                    SubCategories= new List<SubCategory>(){
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1001, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 3.1"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1002, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 3.2"},
                    new SubCategory(){ Id=1003, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 3.3"},
                    }
                },

            };

            return categories;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Register the service in Startup.ConfigureServices method:

   ```
        services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
   ```
4. Then, in the MVC controller, using the following code to get the category and subcategory:

   ```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    { 
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context; //db context.
        private readonly IRepository _repository;
        public HomeController( ApplicationDbContext context, IRepository repository)
        { 
            _context = context; 
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public IActionResult CreateIndex() {

            //get the categories.
            ViewBag.CategoryId = _repository.GetCategories().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value= c.Id.ToString(),Text = c.CategoryName }).ToList();

            return View();
        }
        //get Subcategory based on the category id
        public IActionResult GetSubCategory(int cid)
        {
            var SubCategory_List = _repository.GetCategories().Where(s => s.Id == cid).FirstOrDefault().SubCategories.Select(c => new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
            return Json(SubCategory_List);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateIndex(ProductViewModel product)
        { 
            return View();
        }
   ```
5. code in the view page (CreateIndex.cshtml), populate only Category dropdown when page loads, then using JQuery to call the action method and populate the subcategory:

   ```
    @model MVCDemo.Models.ProductViewModel

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "CreateIndex";
    }

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="CreateIndex">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label asp-for="CategoryTypeId" class="control-label">Category Type</label> 
                        <select asp-for="CategoryTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        </select>  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId" class="control-label">SubCategory Type</label> 
                        <select asp-for="SubCategoryTypeId" class="form-control"></select> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("select#CategoryTypeId").change(function () {
                var cid = $(this).val();

                $("select#SubCategoryTypeId").empty();

                $.getJSON(`/Home/GetSubCategory?cid=${cid}`, function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("select#SubCategoryTypeId").append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
    }
   ```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: How i can done this with fetch data from database ? your method is right but i tried with fetching data from my database and it's not worked (using EF)

Comment: Hi @DishankPatil, Do you meet any error when fetch data from database? From your description you are using EF, instead of EF core, right?

Comment: using EF core and i don't have any error during fetch data from database but my subcategory can't shown when use database to fetch data . Your method is right and worked properly but using database i can't get second dropdown data after selecting first dropdown

Comment: First, you could set a break point in the GetSubCategory action method, and check whether you could get the correct Category Id. Then, based on the category id to query the subcategory table, the code like this: `var SubCategory_List=_db.SubCategory.Where(s => s.CategoryId == cid).Select(c => new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.SubCategoryName }).ToList();`, you could also set a break point to check result, then return this list. Finally, if still not working, set a debugger in the jquery method, make sure you are getting the data and using the right JS selector to populate the records.

Answer (score 1):

There should be nothing special about this in ASP .Net Core, since the views are still built from basic HTML and CSS and you can use JS.

I‘d recommend to follow this tutorial from W3Schools about the topic: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_cascading_dropdown.asp

As you can see, in the tutorial the use this nested array as Dropdown data:

```
var subjectObject = {
  "Front-end": {
    "HTML": ["Links", "Images", "Tables", "Lists"],
    "CSS": ["Borders", "Margins", "Backgrounds", "Float"],
    "JavaScript": ["Variables", "Operators", "Functions", "Conditions"] 
  },
  "Back-end": {
    "PHP": ["Variables", "Strings", "Arrays"],
    "SQL": ["SELECT", "UPDATE", "DELETE"]
  }
}
```

If your Dropdown data is static you could directly put it in the JS code, but I‘d recommend to generate it on the server side and then either:

1. pass it as view data, serialize it to json and replace the array initialization in the JS code with your literal json string
2. do a second request from the client to the server (e.g. using XHR) to some kind of API endpoint and load the Dropdown data as json, then deserialize it and put the data into the dropdown data array. (Don’t forget to reload the actual dropdown elements options in this case)

Feel free to ask for clarification if something was not easy to understand.